# Selecting a Random Row from SQLite Table with Where?

Tags: sqlite

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE records (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                    question TEXT, answer TEXT, category INTEGER)
```

Giving a specific category value (let's say 2), I want to select a random row from that category. That's how I imagine the solution:

```
Select   question, answer, category //I think there is something missing
From     records
Where    category=2
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it like that :

```
SELECT question, answer, category
FROM records
WHERE category=2 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
```